# Pass C++ Eigen matrix to Matlab mex output

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen

How can I pass an [Eigen Matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) as a Matlab output parameter?

I tried this from [[EIGEN] How to get in and out data from Eigen matrix:](http://%20http://dovgalecs.com/blog/eigen-how-to-get-in-and-out-data-from-eigen-matrix/#comment-55942)

```
MatrixXd resultEigen;   // Eigen matrix with some result (non NULL!)
double *resultC;                // NULL pointer
Map<MatrixXd>( resultC, resultEigen.rows(), resultEigen.cols() ) = resultEigen;
```

But it lack information, how to pass the info in resultC to plhs[0] ?
Also, when I run the code using this Map, Matlab closes.

Comment: You cannot get an `Eigen Matrix` into `Matlab`. What you can do is compute a lot using `Eigen` and use the underlying data to create an object, which `Matlab` understands and add it to `plhs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first allocate the output MATLAB array, then create an `Eigen::Map` around it:

```
MatrixXd resultEigen; // Eigen matrix with some result (non NULL!)
mwSize rows = resultEigen.rows();
mwSize cols = resultEigen.cols();
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rows, cols, mxREAL); // Create MATLAB array of same size
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> map(mxGetPr(plhs[0]), rows, cols); // Map the array
map = resultEigen; // Copy
```

What this does is make an Eigen matrix (`map`) that has the MATLAB array (plhs[0]) as data. When you write into it, you are actually writing into the MATLAB array.

Note that you can create this map before doing your Eigen calculations, and use it instead of `resultEigen`, to avoid that final copy.

Note also that you can do exactly the same thing with the input arrays. Just make sure they are of class `double` (using `mxIsDouble`), or things might go horribly wrong... :)