# Return Eigen complex matrix to MATLAB in MEX function without extra copy

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, mex, eigen3

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163426/pass-c-eigen-matrix-to-matlab-mex-output) shows how to return a double matrix to MATLAB using a map object.

The following works for non-complex data:

```
double *outputPtr;
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)n, (mwSize)m, mxREAL);
outputPtr = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
Map<MatrixXd> output(outputPtr, n, m);
```

Since MATLAB stores real and complex elements of a matrix separately rather than interleaved, I don't think you can directly map to `MatrixXcd`. This is what I'm trying but it doesn't write to the data at `plhs[0]`:

```
double *outputReal, *outputImag;
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)n, (mwSize)m, mxCOMPLEX);
outputReal = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
outputImag = mxGetPi(plhs[0]);
MatrixXcd outputMat(n,m);
outputMat.real() = Map<MatrixXd>(outputReal,n,m);
outputMat.imag() = Map<MatrixXd>(outputImag,n,m);
```

I think The problem with that is that it's copying the data in those maps to the real and imaginary parts of `outputMat`. So not only does this do an unnecessary copy on initializing but changes to a matrix assigned this way won't touch the data at the output pointer.

Is there a way to initialize the output matrix in such a way that its real and imaginary data will be stored at `mxGetPr(plhs[0])` and `mxGetPi(plhs[0])`?

Comment: Eigen currently only supports interleaved storage for complex values, so you will need to set up two separate output Maps.

Comment: Since MATLAB R2018a complex numbers are stored interleaved. You need to compile your MEX-files with the `-R2018a` option, otherwise complex data will be copied into separate real and imaginary arrays for backwards compatibility. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-support-for-interleaved-complex.html

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Cris Luengo for pointing me in the right direction. Here's what I got to work.

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)n, (mwSize)m, mxCOMPLEX);
auto* Poutput = reinterpret_cast<complex<double>*>(mxGetComplexDoubles(plhs[0]));
Map<MatrixXcd> output(Poutput, n, m);
```

Then when compiling make sure to give mex the -R2018a flag which will build for interleaved complex data.